# How to detect exceptions as errors in emacs *compilation* buffer?

Tags: exception, error-handling, emacs

I'm running (c++ / gtest / bazel) unit-tests within emacs (ver 26.3) with results displayed in the *compilation* buffer. I would like unexpected exceptions to be detected there as errors. Exceptions start with "C++ exception with description" and it's easy to add it compilation error regex:

```
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist '("^C\\+\\+ exception with description"))
```

The exception lines are properly recognized as indicated by the underline.

[image]

**First problem**: since exceptions don't report file and line numbers, running M-] (next-error) now prompts for a file in the minibuffer. I would like it to just mark the line in the *compilation* buffer.

**Second problem**: even tough the regex detects the exception it's not reported in the mode line as error. In the status fragment `(Compilation: exit [3] [1 0 0]` the last part should be `[3 0 0]`.

Comment: If you get exceptions, you should use a *debugger* to catch the exception as it happens, and locate where in *your* code it happens. In the debugger you can also examine variables and see their values to make sure they are fine.

Comment: In this specific case you try to use index `1` in an empty vector (the size is `0`). This is probably a case you should have added to your tests (if you haven't already) but using asserts or checks that handle exceptions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't believe they're asking how to fix any errors; just how to better highlight them when compiling inside Emacs.  (It's a completely Emacs-centric question.)

Comment: @phils One problem is that the errors aren't compilation errors, but run-time errors (essentially crashes).

Comment: It doesn't matter?  Emacs isn't the compiler -- it's just processing the output as text.

Comment: [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude): as [phils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324105/phils) perceptively pointed out, this question is exclusively about **reporting of test results in Emacs**.

Comment: [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude): You are also incorrect about run-time errors here. Regular test result failures (for instance: ```assert-that(x, is(2))``` when x is not 2) are also run-time errors caused by assert exceptions; except that they are handled by testing frameworks. You can see such a run-time error properly handled here starting with the line ```algo/sort/insertion-sort_unittest.cpp:21: Failure```.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the **first problem** I had to use the full format of the regex list element:

> (REGEXP FILE [LINE COLUMN TYPE HYPERLINK HIGHLIGHT...])

and set the *HYPERLINK* to non-existing captured sub-expression. See below:

```
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist
         '("^\\(C\\+\\+ exception with description\\) .*thrown in the test body\\."
           nil nil nil                       ;; file line column
           2                                 ;; type (2-error, 1-warning, 0-info)
           99                                ;; hyperlink
           (1 compilation-error-face)
           ))
```

Unfortunately, even explicitly setting the type *TYPE* to 2 didn't make it count as error in the status line; so the **second problem** still stands.